# What does "##x" mean while defining a macro

Tags: c++, macros

I am working on some old code; there is a macro in it defined as below:

```
class SymbolToAdd
{
public:
    SymbolToAdd(char *symbolName, FUNCPTR funcPtr);
        SymbolToAdd(char *funcName,
        char *funcHelp,
                    FUNCPTR funcPtr); // Add function with help string
};

#define SANB_OS_REG_FUNC(funcName) static SymbolToAdd funcName##x(#funcName, (FUNCPTR)funcName);

int some_func()
{
//some operations
...

}SANB_OS_REG_FUNC(SANB_OS_REG_FUNC);
```

Can anyone tell me what it means by `funcName##x`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a *concatenation* operator. It adds the left part with the right part.

Example:

```
#define M(a, b)  a ## b
```

If used like

```
printf("%d\n", M(1, 2));
```

then the macro will be replaced by the concatenation of `1` and `2` (i.e. `12`):

```
printf("%d\n", 12);
```

Answer (score 2):

The ## (double number sign) operator concatenates two tokens in a macro invocation (text and/or arguments) given in a macro definition.

If a macro XY was defined using the following directive:

```
 #define XY(x,y)    x##y
```

the last token of the argument for x is concatenated with the first token of the argument for y.